# ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate in Top2Vec Error

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation, word2vec, word-embedding

docs = ['Consumer discretionary, healthcare and technology are preferred China equity  sectors.',
'Consumer discretionary remains attractive, supported by China’s policy to revitalize domestic consumption. Prospects of further monetary and fiscal stimulus  should reinforce the Chinese consumption theme.',
'The healthcare sector should be a key beneficiary of the coronavirus outbreak,  on the back of increased demand for healthcare services and drugs.',
'The technology sector should benefit from increased demand for cloud services  and hardware demand as China continues to recover from the coronavirus  outbreak.',
'China consumer discretionary sector is preferred. In our assessment, the sector  is likely to outperform the MSCI China Index in the coming 6-12 months.']

model = Top2Vec(docs, embedding_model = 'universal-sentence-encoder')

while running the above command, I'm getting an error that is not clearly visible for debugging what could be the root cause for the error?

Error:

### 2021-01-19 05:17:08,541 - top2vec - INFO - Pre-processing documents for training
INFO:top2vec:Pre-processing documents for training
2021-01-19 05:17:08,562 - top2vec - INFO - Downloading universal-sentence-encoder model
INFO:top2vec:Downloading universal-sentence-encoder model
2021-01-19 05:17:13,250 - top2vec - INFO - Creating joint document/word embedding
INFO:top2vec:Creating joint document/word embedding
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 6 calls to <function recreate_function..restored_function_body at 0x7f8c4ce57d90> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 6 calls to <function recreate_function..restored_function_body at 0x7f8c4ce57d90> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
2021-01-19 05:17:13,548 - top2vec - INFO - Creating lower dimension embedding of documents
INFO:top2vec:Creating lower dimension embedding of documents
2021-01-19 05:17:15,809 - top2vec - INFO - Finding dense areas of documents
INFO:top2vec:Finding dense areas of documents
2021-01-19 05:17:15,823 - top2vec - INFO - Finding topics
INFO:top2vec:Finding topics

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model = Top2Vec(docs, embedding_model = 'universal-sentence-encoder')

2 frames
<**array_function** internals> in vstack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
281     if not isinstance(arrs, list):
282         arrs = [arrs]
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
284
285

<**array_function** internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use more docs and unique words for it to find at least 2 topics. As an example, I just multiply your list by 10 and it works:

```
from top2vec import Top2Vec

docs = ['Consumer discretionary, healthcare and technology are preferred China equity  sectors.',
'Consumer discretionary remains attractive, supported by China’s policy to revitalize domestic consumption. Prospects of further monetary and fiscal stimulus  should reinforce the Chinese consumption theme.',
'The healthcare sector should be a key beneficiary of the coronavirus outbreak,  on the back of increased demand for healthcare services and drugs.',
'The technology sector should benefit from increased demand for cloud services  and hardware demand as China continues to recover from the coronavirus  outbreak.',
'China consumer discretionary sector is preferred. In our assessment, the sector  is likely to outperform the MSCI China Index in the coming 6-12 months.']

docs = docs*10 
model = Top2Vec(docs, embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder')
print(model)
```

> <top2vec.Top2Vec.Top2Vec object at 0x13eef6210>

I had few (30) long docs of up to 130 000 characters, so I just split them into smaller docs every 5000 characters:

```
docs_split = []
for doc in docs:
    skip_n = 5000
    for i in range(0,130000,skip_n):
        docs_split.append(doc[i:i+skip_n])
```